# How to click and edit each of the html cells in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var r = 0,
    c = 0;
  for (x in localStorage) {
    var row = table.insertRow(r),
      obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(x));
    for (i in obj) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(c);
      cell.innerHTML = obj[i];
      c += 1
    }
    r += 1;
    c = 0;
  }

  for (var a = 0; a < table.length; a += 1) {

  }

  table.rows[a].cells[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var ask = prompt("Input");
    this.innerHTML = ask;
  });

  table.rows[a].cells[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var ask = prompt("Input");
    this.innerHTML = ask;
  });

  table.rows[a].cells[2].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var ask = prompt("Input");
    this.innerHTML = ask;
  });

  table.rows[a].cells[3].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var ask = prompt("Input");
    this.innerHTML = ask;
  });
};
```

This code on load loops through the saved local storage JSON objects and then prints them into a table each object takes a row and the values are in the cells what i want is to be able to click and edit each of these rows this code only works for the first row and not the others so what should i do?

Comment: Your reference to `table.rows[a]` is outside the for-loop ...

Comment: Removed snippet feature from your OP because there is nothing to run (no HTML code).  I also removed the [tag:jquery] tag since there is nothing in your OP that mentions it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code inside the `for` loop

```
for (var a = 0; a < table.length; a++) {

  table.rows[a].cells[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var ask = prompt("Input");
    this.innerHTML = ask;
  });

  table.rows[a].cells[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var ask = prompt("Input");
    this.innerHTML = ask;
  });

  //more table.rows.....
}
```

Using jQuery is very simple:

```
$(function(){
   $('table td').click(function(){
      var ask = prompt("Input");
      $(this).html(ask);
   });
});
```

Comment: that's what i did in the first place but nothing happens not even an error

Comment: Thank you so much my friend jQuery works perfectly just as i want. I just sometimes try to do everything with plain JavaScript :D and i'm still curious why the above Vanilla JS didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You add event outside of the loop

```
for (var a = 0; a < table.length; a += 1) {
  for(var j=0;j<3;j++){
    table.rows[a].cells[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
      var ask = prompt("Input");
      this.innerHTML = ask;
    });
  }
}
```